# Javascript array : problems with array declaration and access

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, declaration

I'm currently working on a little project in order to learn the Js and the OOP. But I have a problem, let me explain the differents steps :

1) My constructor :

```
function Ammo(ammoId,posX,posY){
    this.id=ammoId;
    this.x=posX;
    this.y=posY;
    $('body').append('<div class="ammo ammo'+this.id+'"></div>');
}
```

2) Prototypes :

```
Ammo.prototype.position = function(){
    $('.ammo'+this.id).css({
        'top': this.y+"px",
        'left': this.x+"px"
    });
}

Ammo.prototype.ammomove = function(){
    this.y-=1;
    this.position();
}
```

3) The call :

```
ammo=[];
var a=1;
function createAmmo(){
    var ammoX=main.x;
    var ammoY=main.y;
    ammo[a] = new Ammo(a, ammoX, ammoY);
    ammo[a].position();
    var animAmmo= setInterval("ammo["+a+"].ammomove()",5);
    a++;
}
createAmmo();
```

My program works perfectly. But when i declare my array with this syntax :

```
var ammo = [];
```

it doesn't work and i have the error "ammo is not defined", whereas this works :

```
ammo = [];
```

Anybody have an idea ? thx !

EDIT : here is my JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/seabon/c057f1oj/

Press Space Bar for call createAmmo()

Comment: Where exactly does the error come from? Check for references to "ammo" in your code. Also, is "ammo" supposed to be global by design or not?

Comment: just x and y position of an another bloc. Check this out : https://jsfiddle.net/seabon/c057f1oj/

Answer (score 0):

`var` keyword defines local variable. That means variable is visible only in current scope.

When you use `ammo = [];` it creates global variable, that can be accessed from `createAmmo()`.

But when you use `var ammo = [];`, it creates local variable. There is method `createAmmo()` declared in same scope, but you can't access this
 scope from body of `createAmmo`.

Pass it as parameter into `createAmmo`.

Comment: Thx for your comment ! I used var a=1; and i can use it in the function. I don't understand..

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ***var*** Keyword to declare a variable *this one will be local to the scope where it's declared* and it can't be accessed in other scopes, and here if you use:

```
var ammo = [];
```

Your `ammo` variable is **local** and it *can't be accessed inside functions* (because every function has its own scope), but when you use:

```
ammo = [];
```

Your `ammo` variable is **global** and *can be accessed in the whole Application*.

**EDIT:**

To correct my answer, in that case you can access both a and ammo inside the createAmmo() function because they are all in the same scope, but the problem here is caused by this instruction:

```
var animAmmo= setInterval("ammo["+a+"].ammomove()",5);
```

It's causing an infinite loop and throws `ammo is not defined` everytime, I tried to debug your code and I think it's caused by the fact that `setInterval()` is interpreting `ammo` as a function and also note that it's an **Antipattern** to pass a String rather than a function to the setInterval() which is stated in [JavaScript **Anti-Patterns** section here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#antipatterns), you can avoid this by calling `ammo[a].ammomove()` without the double quotes like this:

```
var animAmmo= setInterval(ammo[a].ammomove(),5);
```

And it will work perfectly, try this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/o3dpp50a/) it logs in the console all the changes of `ammo`.

Comment: thx for your response. You said "Your ammo variable is local and it can't be accessed inside functions". And what about my variable "var a=1;" ? I can use it in the function

Comment: In this case you can use both a and ammo because they are in the same scope with createAmmo(), the problem is with the setInterval instruction, take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.. The setInterval is exec one-time. I give you my jsfiddle (press space bar for the ammo). You'll see it works. But if you add "var", it doesn't works.. https://jsfiddle.net/seabon/c057f1oj/

Comment: Even with the var it works perfectly, I updated your  [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c057f1oj/1/).

Comment: Nope, when you press space bar, there is still the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: ammo is not defined. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Yes you are right, but when I remove the double quotes `"` from here `setInterval(ammo[a].ammomove(),5);` it works, take a look at this [**Edited fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c057f1oj/2/).

Comment: Yes it's ok for the console but the setInterval doesn't work whereas without the "var" it works.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this! 
This is exactly the answer to your problem!
When using `var` keyword, you can't define it for a second time inside the same scope! you can't override this in the same scope.

JavaScript scope is not code inside `{...}`. It covers all codes inside `function xx(){...}`. So, when you write `ammo=[]` and `a=1` and `ammo[a]`, JavaScript tries to define another variable with the same name and then successfully  override the global `ammo` array! This succeeds because  there is no `var` keyword. When `var` keyword is present, ammo[1] is not known, so it is not defined! Remember that array index starts from 0.

with ammo[a] it works as if you try to access/assign a value to a property whose name is `1` of a new object `ammo`.

Just change `a=1` to `a=0`

Comment: i didn't understand :/